# Starting Node server from Scala app with environment variables

Tags: node.js, scala, shell, environment-variables

I am trying to start a Node server from a Scala app using a shell script but when I try to add environment variables I am getting the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "TEST_ENV_VAR=fake-key": error=2, No such file or directory`

The code looks like this:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path}
import scala.language.postfixOps

@main def app() =
    val path = Path.of(scala.sys.props.get("user.home").get + "/projects")
    
    s"TEST_ENV_VAR=fake-key node $path/node-server/server.js" !!
```

It looks like it is trying to run the environment variables instead of the server. Is there a way to get it to recognize them correctly? I have been able to run a node server successfully using this method when I don't include the environment variable.

Thank you!

Comment: `TEST_ENV_VAR=fake-key` is a shell command, when you run a program from the **JVM** using the process API you are not in a shell, you may launch bash and then inside bash launch your command but that would be unnecessary, there should be a way to pass the env to the process to run, probably easier just calling the **Java** API directly instead of using the fancy DSL from **Scala**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the `scala.sys.process.Process` object:

```
import java.io.File

import scala.sys.process.*

@main def app() =
  val file = File(scala.sys.props.get("user.home").get + "/projects")
  Process("node node-server/server.js", Some(file), "TEST_ENV_VAR" -> "fake-key").!!
```